# What is a good GTD app with cloud sync on iPhone, iPad, and Mac?

Tags: iphone, ipad, software-recommendation, applications, mac

I am looking for a good GTD (todo/task/project management) app that has cloud sync. I'd like it to be on my iPhone, iPad and Mac. Web app would be nice, too.

OmniFocus is the closest thing I've found but it seems too expensive.

Things don't have clound sync... only WiFi sync is available for Things.

Do you know of any GTD app I'm looking for?
Thanks!

Comment: Devs are working *full speed* (sic) on Cloud sync for Things though http://culturedcode.com/status/

Comment: Don't rely on Things development cycle. Notoriously slow.

Comment: You're not going to find a tool as good as OmniFocus. Is it expensive? Yes. Is it worth it? Yes. I've paid for the Mac, iPhone, and iPad versions (the latter is my favorite for most OF uses) and never regretted a penny of it. You're getting an app from a well-known company with an established track record of actually *shipping* what others only talk about in their "road map" including their own sync server. They're doing this with multiple apps, too. I bought OmniFocus/Mac 3.5 years ago and it has continually improved, for free, over that time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check Wunderlist by 6Wunderkinder: http://www.6wunderkinder.com/wunderlist/

It's free. Iphone and ipad apps are available on itunes app store.

Comment: Looks great but it looks like there's no recurring task feature...

Comment: I've looked at this a few months ago, but it seems that they recently added web app, ipad app and etc. I'll give this a second try...

Answer (score 2):

I found a good, cheap alternative to OmniFocus in [ToodleDo](http://www.toodledo.com/). It is browser-based (it doesn't get much more "cloud" than that), but they also have an iOS app for offline use. I've been using it for a few years now and have had little complaints even at their prices (free to a fraction of OmniFocus).

As a sidenote, OmniFocus does support cloud-based syncing. [From the product page:](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnifocus/)

> **Sync**
>
> You can’t accomplish your goals if you
>   don’t have them with you. OmniFocus
>   synchronizes your task database with a
>   server or disk, so that all of your
>   Macs, your iPhone, and your iPod Touch
>   are up-to-date. Sync over your local
>   network using Bonjour, through the
>   cloud using MobileMe or any standard
>   WebDAV server, or even with something
>   as simple as a USB drive.

I believe this is a recent development since their iOS apps. OmniGroup products are not cheap, but they are definitely worth the expense.

Comment: Toodledo is ok, but I really don't like their web UI...

Comment: @BrianKim: I agree that TD's UI isn't ideal, but there are worse out there, and for a web-based system, it's still very useful. I think it would be easy to dismiss all of the apps in the responses for one reason or another, but you'll have to try some of them for a little while each before settling on one. I did. It was a real drag moving content from one to another, but now I've been working with ToodleDo longer than any other system I've used.

Comment: Toodledo has been around for a long time and many apps use Toodledo as a sync hub in the cloud, e.g.  Awsome note (http://www.bridworks.com/anote/en/main/index.php)

Comment: My main devices for using GTD app are Mac and iPad. Toodledo is web and iPhone. Yes there are many todo apps that use Toodledo for syncing but haven't found a really good one that's on Mac and iPad as well. Having web app is a plus but I prefer native app on Mac. I guess that leaves me with only OmniFocus...

Answer (score 2):

- [Doit.im](http://www.doit.im/) which has a web app + iPhone and Android apps. What sets Doit.im appart from e.g. toodledo and producteev is that it is more tailored towards GTD rather than generic task management (though inspired by GTD).
- [Dejumble](http://www.dejumble.com/) is a Mac app which does cloud sync with its companion iPhone app.

I have used both apps, but I am sticking with Omnifocus. Doit.im is free, and Dejumble is not. I have had some high CPU usage issues with Dejumble too.

Edit: I would also say that Doit.im has more organizational features/attributes per task than wunderlist.

Answer (score 2):

I  use Things. Since version 2, it now has a Cloud synch option. I can enter or move items on my iPad and iPhone, as well as Macs running either 10.6.8 or 10.8.5. I haven't upgraded to Mavericks yet, so can't comment on how it works there.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Producteev](http://www.producteev.com/) - it's got a great iOS and Web app, and a Mac desktop app coming soon. It seems a bit more fully featured than Wunderlist as well. It's also got a recurring tasks feature, push notifications...

There website looks a bit cluttered, but the service does work pretty well.

[image]

I've tried a bunch of different apps, and so far this is the most usable/reliable one I've found.

Comment: I found the web interface a bit slow and could not stand it. (slow as in too many clicks needed)

Comment: Really? Once you're logged in, it's just as simple as entering a task in the top bar and clicking add. I sign in with my Google account, so that's very simple too. What part are you finding slow?

Answer (score 1):

Just learned about http://getflow.com the other day. Looking good, but a bit expensive, I think...

Comment: getflow is quite new, so you never know what will happen in the future...

Comment: No recurring task...

Comment: they do have recurring tasks now.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all of those above and, I'm a big wunderlist person but, I just found Workflowy. This is a simple and clean program. The designer does a great job at tutorials to walk you through. For me it just works, I tend to over organized with some of the other programs, which destroys the purpose of using them, to get things done. hope this helps. Blessings-

https://workflowy.com/